# Does "squinting" make you concentrate better on a logic test?

Tags: brain, vision, eyes, anatomy, perception

We have all had those moments of intense concentration on some tough exam, perhaps a college test or whatever...

Why is it that when we squint, it feels like we can focus and concentrate better on the test, and get answers more easily?

Do we actually get a better mental performance when we are squinting?  If so, why?

Comment: Isn't it a social tool to show others you're thinking. Could you cite something that actually says it helps focus?

Comment: @GoodGravy the use in the situation you mention is correct. But and additional usage, at least for me, is when attending a lecture and if very sleepy, closing my eyes or even keeping them half closed reduces drowsiness and increases focus on the talk. My guess is it has something to do with reducing resource consumption. Or maybe an effect similar to what happens with blind people that get other senses enhanced. But these are just wild guesses, can't back them up.

Comment: @ddiez Sorry to be awkward, but when I'm squinting due to tiredness I'm straining to keep my eyes open, not enhance my focus! It's semantics sure, until you assume it enhances normal focus. If you don't think Ilan's answer is correct I think you're mixing up "enhanced focus" with something else.

Comment: @GoodGravy, OK. Are we talking about sight focus or mental focus? In my case I am talking about mental focus (i.e. the ability to enhance concentration). It seems to me that the OP refers to this meaning whereas Ilan's answer is dealing with sight focus (and in that regard it seems like a fine answer to me).

Comment: @GoodGravy To add a bit more detail, when tired, of course I also have to force my eyes open because they tend to close themselves. However, if I give up and close my eyes or put them half opened, then I somehow get a bit of relief and can concentrate better. Also, when thinking about some difficult problem, like mathematics, sometimes I close my eyes and that allows me to concentrate better in the problem. I have seen others doing the same... but maybe it is us! Again, all this refers to mental focus rather than sight focus.

Answer (score 3):

The phenomenon in question is probably related to people with uncorrected/undercorrected [myopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myopia).

This "ancient" phenomenon is called [stenopeic slit effect](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1444-0938.1932.tb01100.x/abstract?) (a case of pinhole effect): when the person squints the visual acuity becomes better because of smaller blur circles: the "slit" between the eyelids is the key point improving blurring.

One can check if it works by creating slit in paper or plastic:

[image]

Some "charlatans/witch-doctors/quacksalver/etc" can "treat" refractive error with [pinhole/stenopeic glasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_glasses):

[image]

It is known that children with refractive errors have attention issues because they cannot see the objects sharply (this is why they can be mistakenly diagnosed with ADHD), thus your concentration improvement related mostly to your vision improve and not a better "understanding".

If you mean by squint using mimic muscles and [corrugator muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrugator_supercilii_muscle) the answer should point out that not a "squint" improves your concentration, but your attempt to improve your concentration causes this type of "squint".

Comment: Doesn't squint mean strabismus?

Comment: @WYSIWYG "squint" means strabismus (eyes misalignment), but also it means "stare" gaze: (google translater):verb
look at someone or something with one or both eyes partly closed in an attempt to see more clearly or as a reaction to strong light.